# Android UI - add buttons dynamically to Gridview

Tags: android, dynamic, user-interface, android-listview, android-gridview

This is where I am stuck now. I am stuck at dynamically adding buttons to gridview.
- My gridview stars with a one button.
- When user clicks that button a context menu , pops up, asking user to enter info, once that is done. A block in the grid view is created with that info
- This is shown in the picture

I have pasted the code. I do not have clear idea on how to do it. I am assuming it will be inflating a new view and adding it to parent(layout or grid ?) view. I do not have much idea on how to code it. I have tried many things from google. I thought I could start from simple image gridview and modify it to my needs but it did not work.

Please provide some directions.

[image]

create_team_new.xml(layout where gridview resides)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentcreateteam"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:background="@drawable/background">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/citytextview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/city"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/teamcity"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/teamname"
    android:layout_width="244dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/teamcity"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gridviewplayer"
    android:text="@string/teamname"
    android:textSize="18sp" >
<requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/createteam"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create Team"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:background="@drawable/red_button"
          style="@+style/button_text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/teamnametextview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/teamname"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/teamname"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/teamname" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/teamcity"
    android:layout_width="244dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cricket"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gridviewplayer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/teamname"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="@string/city"
    android:textSize="18sp" >


</AutoCompleteTextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/radiotextview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/teamcity"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Pick a Sport" />


<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridviewplayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/createteam"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pick_sport"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/gv_bkg"
 android:padding="5dp"
    android:numColumns="4" >

</GridView>



<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/pick_sport"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/createteam"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radiotextview"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/cricket"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cricket" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/soccer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Soccer" />
</RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

gv_createplayer.xml(view to be inflated inside gridview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<Button  android:id="@+id/btn_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text= "+"

    android:background="@drawable/red_button">

</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

PlayerAdapter.java(gridview Adapter)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class PlayerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {};
        /*  R.drawable.gridview_createteam, R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4,
            R.drawable.pic5, R.drawable.pic6,
            R.drawable.pic7, R.drawable.pic8,
            R.drawable.pic9, R.drawable.pic10,
            R.drawable.pic11, R.drawable.pic12,
            R.drawable.pic13, R.drawable.pic14,
            R.drawable.pic15
    };
*/
    // Constructor
    public PlayerAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = new View(mContext);
        view.inflate(mContext, R.layout.gv_createplayer,null);

        return view;


    }


}
```

Comment: Looks possible to me 2, why wouldn't it be? just a small tip on listiview. Having a listview will disable having a scrollview. Which in you case seems necessary. So I would advice to inlate and add to a view than using a listview

Comment: For your parent layout you should use a RelativeLayout, So it will be easy to "stick" button 3 to the bottom of the parent layout

Comment: @ user1281750: Thanks!!!! **I would advice to inlate and add to a view than using a listview**. Can you please describe the one in bold? I am learning my application :)

Comment: I have updated my problem above. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) How to create a list view inside a main view, only using a half of the screen.

This is done by the weight attribute. A rough example for your sketch: The top wrapper (edittexts and buttons) has a weight of .45, the listview has a weight of .45 and the footer has a weight of .1. You can specify the weight-sum in the surrounding view; but default should be 1.

> 2) How to populate list view in grid manner (a row of two columns will repeat itself)

Well, with the [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) (the adapter API is the same) (:

Comment: Awesome ideas!! Let me work on these and I will check back with some code and If I have issues :)

Comment: Is adding a Button with a custom label String all you want to do? Or do you need to add a custom view?

Comment: thanks...when user click "+" button..contact picker comes up....user should be able to select one or multiple contacts...once they finish selecting ... the grid is populated with the selected contacts in the form of buttons.....now if user long press any of the buttons..a pop menu comes up with edit or delete options....."+ button" always remain at position (1,1)

Comment: In this case you need to store some reference to the contact's user entry .You may consider writing a User-class that keeps the reference and additional data like the name if you need it. You should then switch to an ArrayAdapter that manages the User-objects in your grid.

Comment: But it looks like you need some more basics before. Have a look at some ListView/ArrayAdapter tutorials (it's the same API for GridView). There's plenty material out there.

Comment: You could also check out the SDK's samples. You can easily integrate them into your Eclipse when launching a new project. Run them on your device, have a look around and check the source of what seems interesting to you. This helps a lot.

Comment: Thanks..I am getting closer.